# FOR XML PATH with duplicate column names

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to get the desired output from MS SQL Server 2012 using FOR XML PATH.

My query is basically this:

```
select field1 as fields, field2 as fields, field3 as fields 
from mytable 
for xml path
```

which yields this xml:  (for values 0,3,7 in the fieldN columns)

```
<row>
    <fields>037</fields>
</row>
```

The output I desire is this:

```
<row>
    <fields>0</fields>
    <fields>3</fields>
    <fields>7</fields>
</row>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Field1 int,Field2 int,Field3 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values (0,3,7),(8,9,10)

Select [fields] = Field1
      ,''
      ,[fields] = Field2
      ,''
      ,[fields] = Field3
 From  @YourTable
 For   XML Path('row')
```

Returns

```
<row>
  <fields>0</fields>
  <fields>3</fields>
  <fields>7</fields>
</row>
<row>
  <fields>8</fields>
  <fields>9</fields>
  <fields>10</fields>
</row>
```